# PHP class refer to second class which refer to first and so on

Tags: php, class, object, reference, hierarchical-data

Sorry for the question title, I don't know how to name this issue, here it is:

I have two classes, Order and Item.
An Order has Many Itens (array of Itens).
An Item refer to its Order (Order object).

The problem is: The Order has its itens, each Item refer to its Order, which has its Itens, which refer to their Order, which refer to its itens, and so on...

The array hierarchy gets infinite.

Also I don't know how to properly construct the Order object.
I have to create its itens and set them to the Order's Item array, but how can I set the Item's Order if the Order isn't yet constructed?

BTW, the data comes from database.
Table Item has the Order_Id.

Comment: why don't you make the order class so it can have an ID or not based on whether the order actually exists. When the order is complete you could then run a `save` method and that would generate the ID using an INSERT, or using the ID run an UPDATE query. If each of the items are connected to the order they will not need the ID until the order is saved so there is no need to store them against the items.

Comment: I already have all necessary data, just need to convert it to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing fance to do, just:

```
class Order
{
    public $id;
    public $item;

    public function setItem(Item $item)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
    }
}

class Item
{
    public $id;
    public $order;

    public function setOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}

$order = new Order();
$item  = new Item();
$order->setItem($item);
$item->setOrder($order);
```

PHP saves only references to the objects, so there will be no endless recursion. Converting such data structures to json or something else, will require some sort of converter, but that is another topic.

Comment: Right! So if I make changes to the Order after setting it to an Item, the changes will propagate, since Item simply points to that Order. How could I miss that, haha thank you very much!

Comment: I noticed something really interesting!

When using "print_r($order)", it echoes 

`[order:protected] => Order Object *RECURSION*`

Comment: Yeah, you are converting to string in that case. That is what I meant with "Converting such data structures to json or something else, will require some sort of converter".